# clang-format (v10.0.0) doesn't recognise keys such as `BraceBreakingStyle` (introduced in v3.7)

Tags: c++, ubuntu-20.04, clang-format

I am on ubuntu 20.04, and I installed clang-format (the default package, v10.0.0), and can't get it to format my c++ files because keys such as "BraceBreakingStyle" (introduced in clang-format 3.7...) are "unknown"...
Here's my terminal output:

```
> which clang-format
/usr/bin/clang-format
> /usr/bin/clang-format --version
clang-format version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
> clang-format -i BaseObject.cpp -style="{BasedOnStyle: google, BraceBreakingStyle: Allman}"
YAML:1:44: error: unknown key 'BraceBreakingStyle'
{BasedOnStyle: google, BraceBreakingStyle: Allman}
                                           ^~~~~~
Error parsing -style: Invalid argument
```

I seriously don't understand what's happening, especially since, after quickly googling, I don't see other people having this issue... Am I missing something?

Help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Rhaaaah!
Ok I got it... the key should be 'BreakBeforeBraces', not 'BraceBreakingStyle'... It is very confusing in the clang-format documentation!

Sorry for this useless post...

Comment: Yep, the `BreakBeforeBraces` is the **key**, the `BraceBreakingStyle` is the enum name for the acceptable set of **values**.  I concur with the documentation being confusing.